# How to color file names in git log?

Tags: git

I can display files changed in a commit using `--name-only` option. What format param should I use in order to have this file list appear as bold green?

`git log --pretty=format:"%ad %Cblue[%an]%Creset %C(red bold)%s%d%Creset %h" --date=short --name-only`

Comment: According to [Git - pretty-formats Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)... pretty easy to guess since you already have `%Cblue` and `%C(red bold)`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Would you like to take a guess? I've already looked through the docs. What is the format parameter that represents file list? For example: `%ad` represents author date.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use your own `git log --pretty=format` options.

In the `--pretty` you can set colors and choose any content you would like to display

---

> ***`format:<string>`***
>
> The format: format allows you to specify which information you want to show. It works a little bit like printf format, with the notable exception that you get a newline with %n instead of \n.
>
> E.g, format:`The author of %h was %an, %ar%nThe title was >>%s<<%n` would show something like this:

```
The author of fe6e0ee was Junio C Hamano, 23 hours ago
The title was >>t4119: test autocomputing -p<n> for traditional diff input.<<
```

> ***`The placeholders are`***:
>
> `%C(…):` color specification, as described in color.branch.* config option; adding auto, at the beginning will emit color only when colors are enabled for log output (by color.diff, color.ui, or --color, and respecting the auto settings of the former if we are going to a terminal). auto alone (i.e. %C(auto)) will turn on auto coloring on the next placeholders until the color is switched again.
>
> `%C(…):` color specification, as described in color.branch.* config option; adding auto, at the beginning will emit color only when colors are enabled for log output (by color.diff, color.ui, or --color, and respecting the auto settings of the former if we are going to a terminal). auto alone (i.e. %C(auto)) will turn on auto coloring on the next placeholders until the color is switched again.
>
> `%Cblue:` switch color to blue
>   `%Cgreen:` switch color to green
>   `%Cred:` switch color to red
>   `%Creset:` reset color
>   `%D:` ref names without the " (", ")" wrapping.
>   `%G?:` show "G" for a Good signature, "B" for a Bad signature, "U" for a good, untrusted signature and "N" for no signature
>   `%GG:` raw verification message from GPG for a signed commit
>   `%GK:` show the key used to sign a signed commit
>   `%GS:` show the name of the signer for a signed commit
>   `%H:` commit hash
>   `%N:` commit notes
>   `%P:` parent hashes
>   `%T:` tree hash
>   `%aD:` author date, RFC2822 style
>   `%aE:` author email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%aI:` author date, strict ISO 8601 format
>   `%aN:` author name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%ad:` author date (format respects --date= option)
>   `%ae:` author email
>   `%ai:` author date, ISO 8601-like format
>   `%an:` author name
>   `%ar:` author date, relative
>   `%at:` author date, UNIX timestamp
>   `%b:` body
>   `%cD:` committer date, RFC2822 style
>   `%cE:` committer email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%cI:` committer date, strict ISO 8601 format
>   `%cN:` committer name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%cd:` committer date (format respects --date= option)
>   `%ce:` committer email
>   `%ci:` committer date, ISO 8601-like format
>   `%cn:` committer name
>   `%cr:` committer date, relative
>   `%ct:` committer date, UNIX timestamp
>   `%d:` ref names, like the --decorate option of git-log(1)
>   `%e:` encoding
>   `%f:` sanitized subject line, suitable for a filename
>   `%gD:` reflog selector, e.g., refs/stash@{1}
>   `%gE:` reflog identity email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%gN:` reflog identity name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%gd:` shortened reflog selector, e.g., stash@{1}
>   `%ge:` reflog identity email
>   `%gn:` reflog identity name
>   `%gs:` reflog subject
>   `%h:` abbreviated commit hash
>   `%m:` left, right or boundary mark
>   `%n:` newline
>   `%p:` abbreviated parent hashes
>   `%s:` subject
>   `%t:` abbreviated tree hash
>   `%w([<w>[,<i1>[,<i2>]]]):` switch line wrapping, like the -w option of git-shortlog(1).
>   `%x00:` print a byte from a hex code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have files starting with #:

```
BWhite=$'\e[1;37m' # bold white, or use any other color you want
ColorOff=$'\e[0m'
git log --pretty=format:"#%ad %Cblue[%an]%Creset %C(red bold)%s%d%Creset %Cgreen%h%Creset" --date=short --name-only | sed "s/^\([^#].*\)/${BWhite}\1${ColorOff}/" | xargs -d '#' echo -e
```

Which produces
[image]

Explanation: I wrap the lines that contain filenames with colors using sed, as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19248/bash-color-output-fails).
You can also encapsulate this code in a function and add it as a git alias.